# How to display whole content of a file

Tags: r

I attempted to read in data from a list of about 120 comma-separated value files into a single data frame in R.  However, R only displays a small portion of the data, like:

```
2499   2003-11-04          NA         NA   2

2500   2003-11-05  3.17000000  0.5240000   2

 [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 769587 rows ]
```

Is there a reason why so many rows were omitted?  Do you know how I can get all the rows to display?

Thanks

Comment: Don't change this option. Use `View` instead. But I don't get what you hope to achieve by looking manually through some 800.000 rows.

Comment: Thanks.  The view() function displays the entire data frame, whereas the console only displays a limited number of rows.  Do you know how I can change the max.print to its default value (before I made that change that @Akrun and wu suggested?  (this is all extra as my original is solved!)

Answer (score 2):

just as @akru, you can use options(max.print= ...) to reset the print option.
the below you can take a reference:

```
#Find system defualt max print rows
getOption("max.print")

#take example
a <- seq(1, getOption('max.print')+99, 1)
print(a)
#the result as follow
# [1]   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10 
#.....
# [9991]  9991  9992  9993  9994  9995  9996  9997  9998  9999 10000
# [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 99 entries ]


#Reset the max print option, the 
options(max.print = length(a))
print(a)
#the result as follow
# [1]   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10 
#.....
#[10096] 10096 10097 10098 10099
```

hope it clear.

Comment: You code works too.  I can see that the program read all my files.  However, I can scroll all the way to the top of the page.  I want to visually inspect the data from beginning to end.  Do you know what I need to do so I can "scroll" up to the beginning of the output?  Not sure what it is.

Comment: Use key board, press 'Pgup' key or 'Pgup' key to scroll your console page .

Comment: PageUp PageDown

Answer (score 1):

After checking the `options()`, change it if needed

```
options(max.print = 1e7)
```

Comment: It worked.  The program read all of the files.  However, I can't scroll all the way to the beginning of my data frame even though the head() shows my first few observations.  I need to be able to visually inspect my entire data set.  How can I expand the scroll bar?

Comment: If this is sufficient, please "accept" the question: it's good etiquette (to thank akrun) and provides a little more clarity to the question page as a whole.